# Ambari hadoop cluster + the best way to Modify configurations

Tags: json, linux, hadoop, hadoop2, ambari

We have ambari cluster , and clients are installed on Linux redhat machines ,

```
yum list | grep ambari-server
ambari-server.x86_64                  2.5.0.3-7               @ambari-2.5.0.3
```

We found a nice way to set a update a value's in ambari cluster as the following:

1. Update a parameter ( from Ambari server machine )

   ```
   /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/scripts/configs.sh set localhost c1 mapred-site "mapreduce.map.memory.mb" "512"
   ```

While:

```
CONFIG_TYPE = mapred-site
CONFIG_KEY = mapreduce.map.memory.mb
```

But we have a little problem here.....:

From my example - mapred-site is a “CONFIG-TYPE”

According to the script –help:

```
<CONFIG_TYPE>: One of the various configuration types in Ambari. Ex:global, core-site, hdfs-site, mapred-queue-acls, etc.
```

So how to know the right CONFIG_TYPE value for the CONFIG_KEY value ?,

For more info about the script:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Modify+configurations  “Edit configuration using configs.sh” paragraph

remark - in order to see all CONFIG-TYPE values and CONFIG_KEY values I generated the following blueprint.json file:

```
 curl  -u admin:admin -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X GET http://101.16.235.2:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP01?format=blueprint -o /tmp/blueprint.json
```

.

```
  grep "\-site" /tmp/blueprint.json


  "tez-interactive-site" : {
  "hdfs-site" : {
  "yarn-site" : {
  "hiveserver2-site" : {
  "ams-hbase-security-site" : {
  "ams-site" : {
  "mapred-site" : {
  "hive-site" : {
  "tez-site" : {
  "webhcat-site" : {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also clone Ambari repo, and grep/parse configuration files like 
https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-server/src/main/resources/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.2.0/configuration/core-site.xml

Per-stack configurations like https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-server/src/main/resources/stacks/HDP/2.6/services/HDFS/configuration/core-site.xml inherit/override values from common-services and previous stack versions.

Hope this helps